# composition of fraction function with restrictions and finding the corresponding graph

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

Given the function:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{x} & x \neq 0 \\
                          0& x = 0
                          \end{cases}
$$
I need to graph the function: $f(f(x))$. This is what I got:
$$
f(f(x)) = \begin{cases}f(\frac{1}{x}) & x \neq 0 \\
                          f(0)& x = 0
                          \end{cases} \\ \iff
$$
$$
\begin{cases}\frac{1}{1 \over x} & x \neq 0 \\
                          0 & x = 0
                          \end{cases} \\ \iff
$$
$$
\begin{cases}x & x \neq 0 \\
                          0 & x = 0
                          \end{cases}
$$

I think my answer is not correct but not sure because we need to choose a graph from the picture below and I'm not sure that "d" is the correct one. Specifically, shouldn't it be $[0,0]$ and not $(0,0)$ as in "d"?
[image]

Comment: Why shouldn't this be correct? Looks good to me. Note, however, that the last definition, $$\begin{cases}x & x \neq 0 \\
                          0 & x = 0
                          \end{cases}$$ may be simplified.

Comment: Looks good. Another way to see it: If $x=0$ then $f(x)=0$, so $f(f(x))=f(0)=0$... otherwise if $x\neq 0$, then $f(x)=1/x$, and $1/x\neq 0$, so $f(f(x))=f(1/x)=1/(1/x)=x$!

Comment: I edited the question and added a picture which should explain better my question.

Comment: @Szmagpie is that an exclamation mark in your comment or factorial sign? If the latter is true I don't follow how $\frac{1}{1 \over x} = x!$

Comment: @Yos That's a really odd question! [ = (question)(question-1)(question-2)...]

Comment: @coffeemath not sure I understand you.

Comment: @Yos Just a bad joke, referring to $n!=n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots,$ and plugging in "question" for $n.$ [Also I thought it clear that SzMagpie meant exclamation in the sense of "obvious" to finish that alternate way to see it.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mention in the comments, you are right in your answer. As can be seen by considering cases. I will right out a full argument, hopefully that helps.

We are evaluating $f (f (x)) $, and $f $ takes two values depending on what its argument is (in this case $f (x) $). Consider cases on this:

Case 1: $f (x) \neq 0$. Then $f (f (x))=1/f (x)$. And what is $f (x)$? Given the definition, and the assumption that $f (x) \neq 0$, we must be in the case when  $f (x)=1/x $, which **only** happens when $x\neq 0$ (again using the definition of $f $).

Case 2: $f (x) =0$. Then $f (f (x)) =0$. Note that this **only** happens when  $x=0$ (by the definition of $f $).

So indeed $$f(f (x))=\begin{cases}x,&x\neq 0;\\
0,&\text {otherwise}.\end{cases} $$

Now notice that this is equivalent to saying  $$f (f(x))=x $$for all $x $. It should then be clear which of the sketches shows the graph of $f (f (\cdot)) $. (Notice that graph (b) is the same as graph (d) except that the function is defined at $0$.)

P.S. it was an exclamation mark